# Force a C# method to pass only positive parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I want to force my method to only accept an integer parameter if it is *positive*. If the method is passed a *negative* integer it should throw a compile time error. What is the best way to achieve this?

Currently I am using `Math.Abs(Int)` inside the method, but I want the error to be at compile time.

Comment: In theory you could use an unsigned int, but in practice that won't help much.

Comment: You seem to assume that every number is positive or negative. What about zero?

Comment: You can't throw a compile-time error for a parameter, which as far as the compiler knows could be anything.

Comment: Can you use [uint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/x0sksh43.aspx)?

Comment: You are better off throwing an ArgumentOutOfRange exception at runtime if the parameter is not correct. Specify in your documentation that it should be a positive integer otherwise the above exception will be thrown. This is just my opinion though.

Comment: A compile-time error? Will your method only be called with literal values, never with variables?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just make the parameter a `uint` or a `ushort`. That will prevent negative input at compile-time. It won't prevent 0, however... I assume you're really after non-negative input rather than strictly positive input.

If your method *has* to accept a signed parameter, then:

- You can validate the argument value, throwing an exception if it's invalid. (This is a *much* better idea than using `Math.Abs` to try to "fix" invalid input.)
- You could use [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) to indicate to other code that the parameter should have a non-negative value, and it will attempt to prove that everywhere you call the method, the value will be non-negative. This won't be enforced by the C# compiler, but it can still be a build-time procedure.

If you go with the exception approach, then you should also have a comprehensive set of unit tests around the code calling your method - and that code should validate *its* inputs as well, of course.

Comment: @Tigran It will make it impossible to ever have an invalid value at runtime; it will ensure static checking of the values to ensure that they are always valid.

Comment: @Tigran Sure it will. Given `void f(uint x)`, it makes `f(-1)` an error, and allows `f(0)` and `f(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Code Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (and [link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970)) and do a static code analysis before compiling, then using:

```
Contract.Requires( parameter >= 0 );
```

Static code analysis is limited, and you should NOT limit to code contracts (you should still throw runtime exceptions). It'll catch obvious things (like passing constants), but will not catch passing in negative values when they come from outside your code (read from disk, from a database, or whatever).

That's just not possible at compile time

Comment: My *very* limited recollection is that Code contracts *can* catch passing negative values when they come from outside your code, but it does so by complaining if you don't validate input (with a `Contract.Ensures` after you validate).

Comment: @Brian yeah, code contracts can do runtime checking too, I was talking about "static code analysis" when I said that... I maybe phrased it wrongly now that I read it

Comment: No, I was also talking about static code analysis.  It will statically catch passing negative values that come from outside your code by failing if any of your functions accept values from outside your code without including a post-condition (usually with `Contract.Ensures`, though I believe that Contracts analyzer is able to understand simple conditionals, so an explicit post-condition may be unnecessary.  Used properly, this is enough to force a c-sharp method to be passed only positive parameters (admittedly this just shifts the problem elsewhere, but it's still a maintenance win).

Comment: @Brian ah, I see... that's actually very nice and interesting... definitely not to "prevent negative values", but one could find other uses for it.

Comment: From a practical perspective, it's *great* for stuff like "prevent negative values." After adding a precondition to the class or interface, the author of `PositiveIntHandler` can completely ignore the possibility of negative values.  The real power comes from the fact that such requirements cascade; when you pass negative ints to `PositiveIntHandler` indirectly, you *still* get static errors (because you are forced to either add a postcondition or a contract to whoever calls `PositiveIntHandler`). I admit this makes Contracts a hassle to add to existing projects.